# Node/React Login System supporting OAuth2 for Alexa/Google Actions development

Tags: reactjs, express, oauth-2.0, google-home, alexa-skills-kit

Does anyone know of any open source solutions for implementing Alexa or Google Actions account linking ?

Using

- passport.js for Express routes to support social login
- npm oauth2-server to implement oauth endpoints

I've put together my experiences as an open source package [react-express-oauth-login-system](https://github.com/syntithenai/react-express-oauth-login-system).

I'm looking for ideas to improve it. If anyone knows any comparable or related tools that I can use or look at for ideas that'd be sweet.